# How to replace particular character with UItextfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield, uitextview

i tried all the ways but no use because of my poor logical skills... The problem is that I need to replace a word in the sentence by uitextfield, so that it looks like a blank, and that too dynamically

For ex: Test arrives on the scene

I need to replace "Test" in the above sentence by UItextfield, so that user can type in uitextfield. Please show me the way to replace it..

I used uitextview to show the question ,And the code is

```
UITextview   *textview = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, currentY, 320.0, myStringSize.height)];
textview.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i. %@", i+1, unhide];
textview.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16.0f];
CGRect frame = textview.frame;
frame.size.height = textview.contentSize.height;
textview.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, currentY, 320.0, frame.size.height+20);
textview.editable = NO;
[scrollMain addSubview:textview];
```

Is there any way to do it...

or Is there any way to find out the coordinates of "Test" in textview?
Help me out guys, thanks in advance.

Comment: First, %i is not really a valid string format. Check out this guide for the valid formats: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

2nd, you need to be a bit more specific. Do you know the string you want to replace? Is it always the first word? What do you want to replace it with? What is the string variable unhide in your code?

Comment: where is %i used for string?

Comment: no its not always first word,

Answer (score 3):

This replaces the word "Test" with the string of your choise:

```
textview.text = [textview.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"test" withString:@"SomeStringToReplaceWithTest"];
```

Comment: @Yassnie: How this answer be correct? Read the question again... I am wondering how +2. :p

Comment: @AKV because he edited the question, it was first: how to replace the string "Test" and now he is asking about coordinates??

Comment: We both answered at the same time, u were 5 seconds earlier than me. ;) He did commented in my answer, but not in yours... !!! You can check my answer, i used UITextField as string, but he want a real UITextField. :D

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Select "Test" in your textView, programatically and find its range

Find the selected Text Range :

```
UITextRange *selectionRange=[textView selectedTextRange];
CGRect selectionStartRect=[textView caretRectForPosition:selectionRange.start];
CGRect selectionEndRect=[textView caretRectForPosition:selectionRange.end];
CGPoint selectionCenterPoint=(CGPoint){(selectionStartRect.origin.x + selectionEndRect.origin.x)/2,(selectionStartRect.origin.y + selectionStartRect.size.height / 2)};
```

Now initialise `textField.frame` with above.

Your text field will come at the place where Test is written.

Comment: But, i need to replace it with uitextfield. UItextfield is not a string, i need to remove that "Test" and put one UITextfield, so that user can guess the answer and type in uitextfield ....i dont want to replace it by string..

Comment: You want to put textField in UITextView/

Comment: yes... i added UItextfield in uitextview.. but not on exact x and y coordinates of "Test".

Comment: @Joker: how Yassines answer is correct ? +2 votes for him!!!!

Comment: what about my answer? got some idea?

Answer (score 0):

do following steps :

```
NSRange wordRange = NSMakeRange(0,10);
NSArray *firstWords = [[str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] subarrayWithRange:wordRange];
```

you will all the words in the array element then replace whichever world you want by one of the above method.
updated:

```
    NSString *test=@"Test arrives on the scene";
NSRange wordRange = NSMakeRange(0,10);
NSMutableArray *firstWords = (NSMutableArray *)[[test componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] subarrayWithRange:wordRange];
[firstWords replaceObjectAtIndex:indexOfstringyouWant withObject:yourTextField.text];
```

then again make the string out of the array.

Comment: i want to add UITextfield.. so that user can enter their own answer

Comment: please give some detail how ur textfield like

Comment: see.. i want to remove or hide or replace that "Test" and add uitextfield at that place. and it looks like  [UITextfield] arrives on the scene.. so that user can add his own answer in the uitextfield...

Comment: I have updated the answer please use any efficient way than this if available